# Relationship Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm having trouble with some Model Relationships.

I have these tables

```
+--------------+-----------------+------+
| Artists      | Artist Features | Tags |
+--------------+-----------------+------+
| ID           | ID              | ID   |
| Name         | artist_id       | name |
| Address      | price           |      |
| Country      | tag_id          |      |
| Email        |                 |      |
+--------------+-----------------+------+
```

I have relationships between Artists and Artist Features
`artists` `has_many` `artist_features` and `artist_features` `has_many` tags. I want to, with a query get all Artists, features and tags based on the structure above, `artist_id` and `tag_id`

I've used the below to get the `artists` and the corresponding `artist_features` but would like to also get the tags too based on the `tag_id`

```
@Artists = Artist.all.artist_features
```

Comment: If an artist feature `has_many` tags then you should have an `artist_feature_id` column on the `tags` table rather than a `tag_id` column on the `artist_features` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an artist feature `has_many` tags, then you need to change your table columns to match this relationship structure.

A `has_many`/`belongs_to` relationship always requires that the model with the `belongs_to` method call has a foreign key column.

In this case, you want to have a set of tags and allow artist features to reference these tags. We can do this by adding another model between `ArtistFeature` and `Tag`, called `ArtistFeatureTag`, with a table `artist_feature_tags`.

Your model structure then would look like this:

Artist: `id`, `name`, `address`, `country`, `email`

```
class Artist
  has_many :artist_features
end
```

Artist Feature: `id`, `artist_id`, `price`

```
class ArtistFeature
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :artist_feature_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :artist_feature_tags
end
```

ArtistFeatureTag: `id`, `artist_feature_id`, `tag_id`

```
class ArtistFeatureTag
  belongs_to :artist_feature
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Tag: `id`, `artist_feature_id`, `name`

```
class Tag
  has_many :artist_feature_tags
  has_many :artist_features, through: :artist_feature_tags
end
```

The extra table may seem unintuitive, but it's necessary to store the relationship between artist features and tags, i.e. multiple artist features may reference the same tag, and these references take the form of `ArtistFeatureTag`s.

Note that this is basically a [has and belongs to many-type relationship](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many), but I've decided to explicitly create a model for the relationship since I think it makes things more clear.

Comment: Thanks Chris, My tags table I don't want to duplicate rows with the same tag name. So having a artist_feature_id on my tag wouldn't work in that scenario? Perhaps my structure isn't very clear!

Comment: Thanks Chris, much appreciated! this is just what I need.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad it helped.